# rows of vertices along a DAG

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, directed-acyclic-graphs

The goal is to query from

```
-- a → b → c → d
-- ↓ ↘   ↘
-- g   e → f
-- ↓
-- h
dag (vertex, successor) as (values
    ('alpha', 'bravo'),
    ('bravo', 'charlie'),
    ('charlie', 'delta'),
    ('delta', null),
    ('alpha', 'echo'),
    ('echo', 'foxtrot'),
    ('bravo', 'foxtrot'),
    ('foxtrot', null),
    ('alpha', 'golf'),
    ('golf', 'hotel'),
    ('hotel', null)
)
```

into

```
'id_foo', 0, 'alpha'
'id_foo', 1, 'bravo'
'id_foo', 2, 'charlie'
'id_foo', 3, 'delta'
'id_bar', 0, 'alpha'
'id_bar', 1, 'bravo'
'id_bar', 2, 'foxtrot'
'id_qux', 0, 'alpha'
'id_qux', 1, 'echo'
'id_qux', 2, 'foxtrot'
'id_fno', 0, 'alpha'
'id_fno', 1, 'golf'
'id_fno', 2, 'hotel'
```

I can do it in two steps.

```
with recursive intermediate as (
    select * from (
        with recursive
            dag (vertex, successor) as (values
                ('alpha', 'bravo'),
                ('bravo', 'charlie'),
                ('charlie', 'delta'),
                ('delta', null),
                ('alpha', 'echo'),
                ('echo', 'foxtrot'),
                ('bravo', 'foxtrot'),
                ('foxtrot', null),
                ('alpha', 'golf'),
                ('golf', 'hotel'),
                ('hotel', null)
            ),
            cte as (
                select
                        vertex,
                        successor,
                        1 as length,
                        vertex as path
                    from dag where successor is null
                union all
                select
                        dag.vertex,
                        dag.successor,
                        length + 1,
                        dag.vertex||'→'||path
                    from dag join cte
                    where dag.successor = cte.vertex
            )
        select
            length, path
            from cte
            where vertex = 'alpha'
        -- 3, 'alpha→bravo→charlie→delta'
        -- 3, 'alpha→bravo→foxtrot'
        -- 3, 'alpha→echo→foxtrot'
        -- 4, 'alpha→golf→hotel'
    )
),
cte as (
    select
            length,
            path,
            -1 as "index",
            '' as vertex,
            path||'→' as rest
        from intermediate
    union all
    select
            length,
            path,
            "index" + 1,
            substr(rest, 0, instr(rest, '→')),
            substr(rest, instr(rest, '→') + 1)
        from cte
        where rest != ''
)
select length, path, "index", vertex from cte
where vertex != ''
order by path, "index";
```

I think doing it this way is wasteful. Is there a possibility without the string joining and splitting, without an intermediate result set?

Target platform is vaguely [modern SQL](http://enwp.org/ISO_9075). The code above was tested and runs with SQLite.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  And I don't get what your query has to do with the results that you specify.

Comment: What's the problem, specifically? Knowing what is a DAG and vertex is qualification for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with recursive
dag (vertex, successor) as (values
    ('alpha', 'bravo'),
    ('bravo', 'charlie'),
    ('charlie', 'delta'),
    ('delta', null),
    ('alpha', 'echo'),
    ('echo', 'foxtrot'),
    ('bravo', 'foxtrot'),
    ('foxtrot', null),
    ('alpha', 'golf'),
    ('golf', 'hotel'),
    ('hotel', null)
),
head (vertex) as (
        select vertex from dag except select successor from dag
),
paths (row, depth, parent_row, vertex, successor) as (
        select row_number() over (), 1, 0::bigint, dag.vertex, dag.successor
                from head
                join dag on (dag.vertex = head.vertex)
        union all
        select row_number() over (), depth + 1, row, dag.vertex, dag.successor
                from paths
                join dag on (dag.vertex = paths.successor)
),
result (path_id, parent_row, depth, vertex) as (
        select row_number() over (), parent_row, depth, vertex
                from paths
                where successor is null
        union all
        select result.path_id, paths.parent_row, paths.depth, paths.vertex
                from result
                join paths on (paths.row = result.parent_row and paths.depth = result.depth - 1)
)
select path_id, depth, vertex
        from result
        order by 1, 2
;
```

Postgresql specific

```
with recursive
dag (vertex, successor) as (values
        ('alpha', 'bravo'),
        ('bravo', 'charlie'),
        ('charlie', 'delta'),
        ('delta', null),
        ('alpha', 'echo'),
        ('echo', 'foxtrot'),
        ('bravo', 'foxtrot'),
        ('foxtrot', null),
        ('alpha', 'golf'),
        ('golf', 'hotel'),
        ('hotel', null)
),
head (vertex) as (
        select vertex from dag except select successor from dag
),
paths (path, successor) as (
        select array[dag.vertex], dag.successor
                from head
                join dag on (dag.vertex = head.vertex)
        union all
        select array_append(paths.path, dag.vertex), dag.successor
                from paths
                join dag on (dag.vertex = paths.successor)
),
result_paths (path_id, path) as (
        select row_number() over (), path
                from paths
                where successor is null
),
result (path_id, depth, vertex) as (
        select path_id, p.nr, p.elem
                from result_paths
                left join lateral unnest (path) with ordinality as p(elem, nr) on true
)
select * from result
        order by 1,2
;
```